# Kubernet Helm Concern

Tags: kubernetes

You have a collection of pods that all run the same application, but with slightly different configuration. Applying the configuration at run -time would also be desirable. What's the best way to achieve this?

a: Create a separate container image for each version of the application, each with a different configuration

b: Use a single container image, but create ConfigMap objects for the different Configurations and apply them to the different pods

c: Create persistent Volumes that contain each config files and mount then to different pods

Comment: For Option A, you don't need to build a separate container image for each version of the application.. init containers can be used to give the main application different config files. So, you could have the same main application container and then one different init container for each different configuration. But I would still prefer option b, unless the config files are too much / there's  some strict and specific request which makes ConfigMaps a no-go

Comment: Please edit the question to include any relevant application source code, and what led you to consider one of these three options.  See the [help/on-topic] for more information about what sorts of questions make sense for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best solution for this would be "b" to use ConfigMaps.
Apply changes to the ConfigMap and **redeploy** the image/pod. I use this approach very often at work.

Edit from @AndD: [...] ConfigMaps can contain small files and as such can be mounted as read only volumes instead of giving environment variables. So they can be used also instead of option c in case files are required.

My favorite command for this

```
kubectl patch deployment <DEPLOYMENT> -p "{\"spec\": {\"template\": {\"metadata\": { \"labels\": {  \"redeploy\": \"$(date +%s)\"}}}}}"
```

Patches a redeploy date to now in spec.template.metadata.labels.redeploy -> date +%s

Option "a" seems to be evenly good, the downside is you have to build the new Image, push it, deploy it. You could build a Jenkins/GitLab/whatever Pipeline to automate this way. But, I think ConfigMaps are fairly easier and are more "manageable". This approach is viable if you have very very many config files, which would be too much work to implement in ConfigMaps.

Option "c" feels a bit too clunky just for config files. Just my two cents. Best Practice is to not store config files in volumes. As you (often) want your Applications to be as "stateless" as possible.

Comment: Just wanted to add that ConfigMaps can contain small files and as such can be mounted as read only volumes instead of giving environment variables. So they can be used also instead of option c in case files are required.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right @AndD Forgot to mention